# how to call azure hosted webhttprelay url from html

Tags: angularjs, ajax, azure, postman, servicebus

I have service hosted in azure. and below is the URL:

binding type - webhttprelaybinding

https://module.servicebus.windows.net/moduleService/webhttp/GetData

when accessing through postman call then, getting below result:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title>
    <subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle>
    <id>uuid:645c26c6-9bc7-4546-8978-bf5e26fc79bd;id=60084</id>
    <updated>2017-02-12T16:41:37Z</updated>
    <generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator>
</feed>
```

Expecting to call getdata method and retrieve JSON data but it just give me above response.

can any one please share me what is wrong here.

Basically, - I need to call from html to service bus url and get response to client side in html.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by your endpoint. I get the same issue here:

[image]

If I input the address https://relytest.servicebus.windows.net/testhttpauth. It give me authentication error (I set Requires Client Authorization as true, and test the address in IE)

[image]

So, I would suggest you double check your url.